# How to use HtmlHelper from App_Data to view in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have create a simple HtmlHelper class in my MVC3 application and put it in "**App_Data\PriceHelper.cshtml**"

code in PriceHelper,cshtml

```
@helper DisplayPrice(double price)
{
    @String.Format("{0:N}",price)
}
```

when i am tried to  use this helper in  my view at that time it not allow me to use @PriceHelper.DisplayPrice().

but if i put hepler method on same view then it work.

please let me know how can use HtmlHelper from App_Data to my view?

Answer (score 3):

The *Razor helpers* can be reused when they are stored in `App_Code` folder not `App_Data`.

You can find more details here: [ASP.NET MVC 3 and the @helper syntax within Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`App_Data` is intended for data resources (xml, text, db files) not code. Use another folder for this, e.g. `Views/Shared.`

My choice would be to create an HTML helper (and put it in the model):

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
    {
        public static string DisplayPrice(this HtmlHelper helper, double price)
        {
            return String.Format("{0:N}", price);
        }
    }
```

used like this in a view:

```
 @Html.DisplayPrice(10)
```